# Update window dimension in title when resized

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I would like to have a window title that updates itself whenever the window gets resized. It should be in a format such that the title would display 
Window Size - [width] x [height] 
But with the result I got a title that displayed _alloca was corrupted.

```
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow *window = NULL; //initialise window with pointer to GLFW handle
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    //initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        //if failed to initialise GLFW
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //minimum OpenGL version 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    //create the window here
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Window Size - " + WINDOW_WIDTH + "x" + WINDOW_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL);

    //if window fail, terminate GLFW
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // set window context as the current context
    glfwSwapInterval(1);            // swap buffer interval

    // initialise GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        // if failed to initialise GLEW
        cerr << "GLEW initialisation failed" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //set key callback function
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    //render loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);    //swap buffers
        glfwPollEvents();           //poll for events
    }

    //close window, terminate GLFW
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Instead of just down voting I could at least know what was it that i have done wrongly. It would be good for a little explanation thanks

Comment: Here's one problem: `"Window Size - " + WINDOW_WIDTH + "x" + WINDOW_HEIGHT` That's not legal C++. Your compiler should have given you an error.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Assuming that `WINDOW_WIDTH` is something similar to `#define WINDOW_WIDTH 300`, this compiles perfectly fine (tested on VS2013). Since the first part is a `const char*` it is possible to add an integer to it (pointer arithmetic).

Answer (score 2):

As @NicoleBolas already mentioned in the comments, the problematic part is

```
"Window Size - " + WINDOW_WIDTH + "x" + WINDOW_HEIGHT
```

This is legal C++ but doesn't do what you expect it to do. Here the value of `WINDOW_WIDTH` is added to the **address** of the `"Window Size"` constant. The result is then a new pointer which points in your case to an invalid memory address.

If you want to append width and height as text, you have to convert the numbers first to a text and concatenate the resulting strings then. One easy method of doing this is by using a `stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "Window Size - " << WINDOW_WIDTH << "x" << WINDOW_HEIGHT;

window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, s.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL);
```